# Speed of beta-decay ejected electrons

Tags: radiation, radioactivity

It is well known that the energy spectrum of the beta-decay electron is continuous; it was confirmed by the Ellis and Wooster 1927 experiment. It means the electron are ejected with speeds that may vary from zero to a maximum.

To date, are there any experiments done to directly measure the speed of the ejected beta electrons through the time-of-flight method? Can someone provide some links.

Comment: Specifically time of flight, and not energy?

Comment: Yes. Strictly time-of-flight which should detected speed near zero to maybe near c.